Delete a file from Program Files folder using VB.Net Application
I am trying to delete a mdb file from "Program Files (x86)" folder and it denies the access permission. When my application installs in a machine, the mdb file is placed in the "Program Files (86)" folder and while running the application, it tries to delete it from that location. But it shows access permission denied error message. I am using VB.Net windows application. Visual Studio 2022 and OS is Win 10 64 bit.
I tried the below ways.
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCOMPANIES\MyDB.mdb"

    If File.Exists(path1) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path1, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)            
    End If

End Sub

The above code doesnt throw any error but asks for entering admin credentials. This is NOT acceptable in my case.
And I tried as shows below :
        Dim path1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCOMPANIES\MyDB.mdb"
        File.SetAttributes(path1, FileAttributes.Normal)
        File.Delete(path1)

It threw below shown error:
       System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCOMPANIES\MyDB.mdb' is denied.'

So, I thought about a new way that i tried to move the file from program files location to some other location and delete the file from there. So I tried below code.
    Dim path1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCOMPANIES\MyDB.mdb"
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(path1)
    Dim destinationPath As String = Path.Combine("C:\MyFolder\MyDB.mdb", filename)
    If File.Exists(destinationPath) Then
       File.Delete(destinationPath)
    End If
    File.Move(path1, destinationPath)

It also threw error as shown below:
   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path is denied.'

How to delete that file from Program Files (86) location using VB.Net code ??
Please help.
Updated :
I installed my app in the ProgramData folder. So the mdb file placed in the C:\ProgramData\MyCompanies\MyDB.mdb . When application runs, it threw the access permission error as before. But I could manually delete files from ProgramData folder.
How I can delete this mdb file using code ????

Is it too late to change the program to use a better location for the database? where to put my access database in computer.

Non-admin users don't have permission to modify the Program Files folder. That's how Windows security works. If the admin prompt is unacceptable to you then either run that app as an admin in the first place or don't put the file there. That's the solution.

I installed my app in the ProgramData folder. So the mdb file placed in the C:\ProgramData\MyCompanies\MyDB.mdb . When application runs, it threw the access permission error as before.

@KitKat you want to install your app into the Program Files directory, but you want your database file in a proper location, as indicated in the link posed by Andrew Morton. Think of it this way, you install MS Office to C:\Program Files\, but you do not save your documents there. It is the same concept.
